# What are ANY-user and information_schema on MySQL Server?

Tags: mysql, centos, debian

I have a few servers that still seem to have the default ANY-user and information_schema.

I would delete it, but they are production servers. It seems very worrisome to me

- What is this Any user that accepts connections from any host?
- What is information_schema?
- I know MySQL is a database server that should be configured, but some security by default seems not a bad idea, e.g. a default PermitRootLoginwithoutPassword, although it might make changer the password harder.

I have set up my server to not accept connections on port 3306 from other machines and might soon place the MySQL server entirely in a virtual network (192.168.x.x).

Answer (score 1):

The "Any" user is used by mysql during installation to check that the database was installed properly. You can safely remove it after the installation.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken `information_schema` was introduced in MySQL v5.0

`information_schema` is the information database where the information about all the other databases is kept. It is a built-in virtual database with the sole purpose of providing information about the database system itself (this includes the name of a database or a table, the data type of a column, access privileges, etc.).

The MySQL server automatically populates the tables in the information_schema. Inside information_schema there are several read-only tables. They are actually views, not base tables, so there are no files associated with them. You can query it, but you cannot change its structure or modify its data.

You can read more on information_schema from [official MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-schema.html)

Regarding `ANY-user` -- sorry, no idea -- don't remember seeing anything like that myself.